# VBA throws an error when a string is changed to a variable with exact string

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

This is my vba code for powerquery function

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Or ORder", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""C:\Users\DDK\Downloads\excel.xlsx""), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Sheet1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Column1"", type any}" & _
        ", {""CROWN"", type any}, {""March 15th, 2021"", type text}, {""Column4"", type any}, {""Column5"", type any}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Top Rows"" = Table.Skip(#""Changed Type"",2)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns"" = Table.RenameColumns(#""Removed Top Rows"",{{""Column1"", ""QTY""}, {""CROWN"", ""ITEM""}, {""March 15th, 2021"", ""Part""}, {""Column5"", ""Price""}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filter" & _
        "ed Rows"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Renamed Columns"", each [QTY] <> null and [QTY] <> """")" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "Our Order"
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Or ORder"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Or ORder]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Or_ORder"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

When the file directory for the source is changed to a variable like this

```
Dim fileOrder as String
fileOrder = "C:\Users\Ddk\Downloads\excel.xlsx"
....
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(fileOrder), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) ""....
```

It throws an error when it reaches `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`. Why is it? Even when it is the exact same string it gives an error `[Expression.Error] The import Order matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?`

The thing is I want user to select the excel file for power query through VBA that's why I need to have a variable on file directory.

Comment: Please, try changing `Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(fileOrder)...` with `Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""" & fileOrder & """)...` You must incapsulate the necessary variabile between double quotes.

Comment: This works!! I should have checked. first I tried with ```" & fileOrder &"``` then I realised my mistake that I should have given one more double quotes. it still didn't work. Actual statement has to have 3 double quotes; one which denotes the string. ```"""``` works

Answer (score 0):

Why not use VBA to write the path to a named cell range, and have powequery read it in?

```
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="RangeName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),
```

or

```
let  Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="RangeName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]), null, true),
```

Comment: ```(""" & fileOrder & """)``` using 3 doubes worked for me.